# 2 dimensional Brownian motion but not 3 dimensional Brownian motion

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $W_t = (W_t^{(1)},W_t^{(2)},W_t^{(3)})$ be 3 dimensional Brownian motion. Let $X=sgn(W_1^{(1)})sgn(W_1^{(2)})sgn(W_1^{(3)})$. Define a 3 dimensional process $M_t$ as follows :

$M_t^{(1)} = W_t^{(1)}, M_t^{(2)} = W_t^{(2)}, M_t^{(3)} = X W_t^{(3)}$

Prove that $(M_t^{(1)},M_t^{(3)})$ is 2 dimensional Brownian motion but $(M_t^{(1)},M_t^{(2)},M_t^{(3)})$ is not a Brownian motion.

Comment: Pretty question. What did you try?

Comment: I was trying to use Levy's characterization of BM. But I failed. I have trouble in getting the right filtration for the process. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show that $(M^{(1)},M^{(3)})$ is a Brownian motion, note that $(M^{(1)},M^{(3)})=(W^{(1)},XW^{(3)})$ where $X=\pm1$ is independent of $(W^{(1)},W^{(3)})$, hence the distribution of $(M^{(1)},M^{(3)})$ is a barycenter of those of $(W^{(1)},W^{(3)})$ and $(W^{(1)},-W^{(3)})$. Since these last two distributions coincide and $(W^{(1)},W^{(3)})$ is a Brownian motion, the proof is complete.

To show that $(M^{(1)},M^{(2)},M^{(3)})$ is not a Brownian motion, note that $M^{(1)}_1M^{(2)}_1M^{(3)}_1=|W^{(1)}_1W^{(2)}_1W^{(3)}_1|$ hence the distribution of $(M^{(1)}_1,M^{(2)}_1,M^{(3)}_1)$ allocates measure zero to the set $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\mid xyz\lt0\}$ while the distribution of 3-dimensional Brownian motion at time $1$ does not. This argument shows that $(M^{(1)}_1,M^{(2)}_1,M^{(3)}_1)$ is not even gaussian.

Comment: Thanks Did! Can you please explain why $(M^{(1)},M^{(3)})$ is independent of $(W^{(1)}),W^{(3)})$?

Comment: Also, if we use Levy characterization on $(M^{(1)},M^{(2)},M^{(3)})$ using quadratic variation we get that it is a BM. Where is the fallacy in this argument?

Comment: I never said that (M^(1),M^(3)) is independent of (W^(1),W^(3)), in fact it is not, even (M^(1)_1,M^(3)_1) is not independent of (W^(1)_1,W^(3)_1).

Comment: About arguments based on quadratic variation, a first problem is that the process M is not adapted to the natural filtration of W--hence I really wonder how one can apply Lévy's characterization.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I didn't read it correctly. How is $X$ independent of $(W^{(1)},W^{(3)})$ ?

Comment: Because $X=YZ$ where $Y$ and $Z$ are $\pm1$, $Y$ is $(W^{(1)}_1,W^{(3)}_1)$-measurable and $Z$ is independent of $(W^{(1)}_1,W^{(3)}_1)$.

Comment: Thanks! With the approach of Levy Characterization - $M_t$ is adapted to the filtration generated by it and all the components are continuous local martingales and they have right quadratic variation term. So why is the conclusion wrong?

Comment: I am not sure you realize the problem. To simplify things, consider a usual Brownian motion $B$ and, for every $t$ in $[0,1]$, $A_t=\mathrm{sign}(B_1)B_t$. Then $A$ is not a local martingale, neither in its own filtration nor in the filtration of $B$.

Comment: Thanks Did for initial answer. It is clear that X is not adapted to the filtration generated by (W^{(1)}), W^{(2)}, W^{(3)}). In that case, I thought M^{(3)} is not a one-dimensional Brownian motion in the first place. So how could (M^{(1)}),M^{(3)}) is a two-dimensional Brownian motion?

Comment: @learning $M^{(3)}$ is a one-dimensional Brownian motion for its own filtration. Likewise for $(M^{(1)}),M^{(3)})$.